# Laravel add/remove input fields update values problem

Tags: laravel

I use add/remove input fields with jquery and have problem when I want to update the values.

In the store() method foreach loop fetches all input fields that I added, while in the update() method foreach loop fetched only first input.

How can I fix this?

I have two tables "attributes(id,name)" and "attribute_option(id,attribute_id,attribute_value").

In edit.balde.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#add").click(function(){
     addRow();
   }}

   function addRow(){
     $("optionsTable").append('<tr><td><input type="text" name="value[]" class="form-control"</td><td><button type="button" class="remove-tr">Remove</button></td></tr>);
   };

   $(document).on('click','.remove-tr', function(){
     $(this).parents('tr).remove();
   });
</script>

<button type="button" id="add">Add row</button>
@foreach($attribute_options as $key=>$option)
<tr>
   <td>
     <input type="hidden" name="option_id[]" value="{{ $option->id }}">
     <input type="text" name="value[]" value="{{ $option->attribute_value }}"> 
   </td>
   <td>
     <button type="button" class="remove-tr">Remove</button>
   </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

in my controller action update()

```
if($request->has('value)){
  $options = $request->value;
  $option_id = $request->option_id;
  foreach($options as $value){
     AttributeOption::where('id','=',$option_id)->update(array(
      'attribute_value' => $value
     ));
  }
}
```

Comment: In update(); what is the output dd($request->value) ?

Comment: value is type of array so i think you should assign options as $options = $request['value'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `$option_id` is also an array and therefore also must be read as an array:

```
if($request->has('value')){
  $options = $request->value;
  $option_id = $request->option_id;
  foreach($options as $key => $value){
     AttributeOption::where('id','=',$option_id[$key])->update(array(
      'attribute_value' => $value
     ));
  }
}
```